# Two simple push functions; one permanently mutates global var, other doesn't, why?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Here are two simple functions that use `push` on a variable passed in:

`(defun push-rest (var) (push 99 (rest var)))`

and

`(defun just-push (something) (push 5 something))`

The first one will permanently mutate the `var` passed. The second does not. This is quite confusing for someone who is learning the scoping behavior of this language:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter something (list 1 2))    
SOMETHING
CL-USER> something
(1 2)
CL-USER> (just-push something)
(5 1 2)
CL-USER> something
(1 2)
CL-USER> (push-rest something)
(99 2)
CL-USER> something
(1 99 2)
```

In `push-rest` why isn't the var's scope local to the function like in `just-push`, when they are both using the same function, `push`?

Comment: It is not a good idea to name a global variable `something` and have local variables `something`. Use `*something*` as the name for the global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Peter Siebel's Practical Common Lisp, Chapter 6. Variables: [This](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html) might help you a lot:

> As with all Common Lisp variables, function parameters hold object references. Thus, you can assign a new value to a function parameter within the body of the function, and it will not affect the bindings created for another call to the same function. But if the object passed to a function is mutable and you change it in the function, the changes will be visible to the caller since both the caller and the callee will be referencing the same object.

And a footnote:

> In compiler-writer terms Common Lisp functions are "pass-by-value." However, the values that are passed are references to objects.

(Pass by value also essentially means copy; but we aren't copying the object; we are copying the reference/pointer to the object.)

As I noted in another comment:

Lisp doesn't pass objects. Lisp passes copies of object references to functions. Or you could think of them as pointers. `setf` assigns a new pointer created by the function to something else. The previous pointer/binding is not touched. But if the function instead operates on this pointer, rather than setting it, then it operates on the original object the pointer points too. if you are a C++ guy, this might make much more sense for you.

Comment: If you're going to copy text from somewhere else, you need a citation.  This text is copied verbatim  from [Practical Common Lisp, Chapter 6. Variables](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I linked directly to the text in the book in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link (light blue/gray on white background next to black text).  Sorry about that.  I'd still suggest making it a bit more conspicuous with something like "According to Peter Siebel's [_Practical Common Lisp_, Chapter 6. Variables](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html): …"

Answer (score 3):

**You can't *push on a variable passed*. Lisp does not pass variables.**

Lisp passes objects.

You need to understand evaluation.

```
(just-push something)
```

Lisp sees that `just-push` is a function.

Now it evaluates `something`. The value of something is a list `(1 2)`.

Then it calls `just-push` with the single argument `(1 2)`.

`just-push` will never see the variable, it does not care. All it gets are objects.

```
(defun push-rest (some-list) (push 99 (rest some-list)))
```

Above pushes `99` onto the rest, a cons, of the list passed. Since that cons is visible outside, the change is visible outside.

```
(defun just-push (something) (push 5 something))
```

Above pushes `5` to the list pointed to by `something`. Since `something` is not visible outside and no other change has made, that change is not visible outside.

Comment: By your explanation, if `something` is just an object that is not visible outside, then why isn't `some-list` also an object not visible outside, and `rest some-list` is a part of that object that is not visible outside?

Comment: @OpenLearner: `something` is not an object. `something` is a variable. `some-list` is also not an object. `some-list` is a variable. `something` points to a list. `some-list` points to a list. `(push 99 (rest some-list))` changes the list destructively. `(push 5 something)` changes the local variable, not the initial list.

Comment: I think the confusing aspect to this behavior is that it is not the passing of the function argument that determines whether we are operating on a pointer to an outside object or a binding to a new local object. Rather, it is the use of `push` that makes that distinction, which is confusing. I'm coming from a language like C++ where either you pass a reference to an object, or you pass by value, and that is determined by the argument list, not by what you actually do inside the function.

Comment: Not really. Lisp doesn't pass objects. Lisp passes _copies of object references_ to functions. Or you could think of them as pointers. `setf` assigns a new pointer created by the function to something else. The previous pointer/binding is not touched. But if the function instead operates on this pointer, rather than setting it, then it operates on the original object the pointer points too. if you are a C++ guy, this might make much more sense for you.

Comment: @OpenLearner: It is just as in many other languages. If you change a local variable, it is not outside visible. If you change the object passed, it can be outside visible. That's nothing special to Lisp - it is special to all languages which pass objects as values - not as copies. Then: `PUSH` is a macro which changes a *place*: it can change global/local variables, cons car/cdr, object slots, hash table entries, and a lot more. You tell `PUSH` what to change and it does the change. Difference: changing a local variable vs. changing a certain cons cell.

Answer (score 3):

`push` works differently when it's passed a symbol or list as it's second argument. Pehaps you might understand it better if you do `macroexpand` on the two different.

```
(macroexpand '(push 99 (rest var))) 
;;==>
(let* ((#:g5374 99)) 
  (let* ((#:temp-5373 var)) 
    (let* ((#:g5375 (rest #:temp-5373))) 
      (system::%rplacd #:temp-5373 (cons #:g5374 #:g5375)))))
```

Now most of this is to not evaluate the arguments more than once so we can in this case rewrite it to:

```
(rplacd var (cons 99 (rest var)))
```

Now this mutates the `cdr` of var such that every binding to the same value or lists that has the same object in it's structure gets altered. Now lets try the other one:

```
(macroexpand '(push 5 something))
; ==>
(setq something (cons 5 something))
```

Here is creates a new list starting with 5 and alters the local functions binding something to that value, that in the beginning pointed to the original structure.  If you have the original structure in a variable `lst` it won't get changed since it's a completely different binding than `something`. You can fix your problem with a macro:

```
(defmacro just-push (lst)
  (if (symbolp lst)
      `(push 5 ,lst)
      (error "macro-argument-not-symbol")))
```

This only accepts variables as argument and mutates it to a new list having 5 as it's first element and the original list as it's tail. `(just-push x)` is just an abbreviation for `(push 5 x)`.

Just to be clear. In an Algol dialect the equivalent code would be something like:

```
public class Node
{
  private int value;
  private Node next;

  public Node(int value, Node next)
  {
    this.value = value;
    this.next  = next;
  }

  public static void pushRest(Node var)
  {
    Node n   = new Node(99, var.next); // a new node with 99 and chained with the rest of var
    var.next = n; // argument gets mutated to have new node as next
  }

  public static void justPush(Node var)
  {
    var = new Node(5, var); // overwrite var
    System.out.print("var in justPush is: ");
    var.print();
  }

  public void print()
  {
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(value) + " ");
    if ( next == null )
      System.out.println();
    else
      next.print();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Node n = new Node( 10, new Node(20, null)); 
    n.print();    // displays "10 20"
    pushRest(n);  // mutates list
    n.print();    // displays "10 99 20"
    justPush(n);  // displays "var in justPush is :5 10 99 20" 
    n.print();    // displays "10 99 20"
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess its a question for me is what exactly the variable in the function's argument represents. We have `var`, a variable local to the function. My understanding is that this is a local binding created when the function runs. That it essentially runs `rplacd` is fine, but why is `rplacd` operating on the object from the outside binding, rather than the local binding? A new variable, `var` is created when the function runs; why isn't `rplacd` operating on that new variable rather than the previous binding?

Comment: @OpenLearner In both cases you have a local binding, but since the object to push is a list, the macro uses `rplacd` instead of `setq`. `rplacd` mutates the actual object while `setq` mutates the (local) binding.

Comment: @OpenLearner I'n not sure other languages you are used to, but I've added an example of the same behavior in Java.

Comment: Thanks, but I've actually never used Java. I'm more of a C++ guy.

Answer (score 0):

```
(push item place)
```

It work as follows　when the form is used to instruct the `place` where this is referred to in the `setf`:

```
(setf place (cons item place))
```

Comment: Yes but why is `place` visible to the outside in one function but not the other?

Comment: @OpenLearner it isn't  copied variable contents (e.g list) that is passed to the function.

Comment: For example, is like a difference of value types and reference types referred to in other languages​​.

Answer (score 0):

Basedon your profile, it looks like you have familiarity with C-like languages.  `push` is a macro, and is the following equivalence is roughly true (except for the fact that this would cause `x` to be evaluated twice, whereas `push` won't):

```
(push x y) === (setf x (list* x y))
```

That's almost a C macro.  Consider a similar `incf` macro (CL actually defines an [`incf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_incf_.htm), but that's not important now):

```
(incf x) === (setf x (+ 1 x))
```

In C, if you do something like

```c
void bar( int *xs ) {
  xs[0] = xs[0] + 1;   /* INCF( xs[0] ) */
}

void foo( int x ) {
  x = x + 1;           /* INCF( x ) */
}
```

and have calls like

```c
bar(zs);               /* where zs[0] is 10 */
printf( "%d", zs[0] ); /* 11, not 10 */

foo(z);                /* where z is 10 */
printf( "%d", z );     /* 10, not 11 */
```

The *same* thing is happening in the Lisp code.  In your first code example, you're modifying contents of some structure.  In your second code example, you're modifying the value of lexical variable.  The first you'll see across function calls, because the structure is preserved across function calls.  The second you won't see, because the lexical variable only has lexical scope.

Sometimes I wonder if Lisp aficionados (myself included) promote the idea that *Lisp is different* so much that we confuse people into thinking that nothing's the same.